# Mix Daemonettes of Slaanesh and Slaves to Darkness, Warhammer AoS

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar, chaos-marauders

I am back in Warhammer AoS! I started years ago with Slaves to Darkness (*i.e.* [chaos marauder](https://www.kuma.cz/warhammer-age-of-sigmar-slaves-to-chaos-chaos-marauders-warhammer-age-of-sigmar/?gclid=CjwKCAjwhaaKBhBcEiwA8acsHPpJyElqSMoKGsT_YLRKDor_Fx8lNh1GehDzJDYf6Ixp5q0i8ySDlBoCSDwQAvD_BwE) and few Chaos knights). However, I couldn't resist to buy the [start to collect Daemons of Slaanesh](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-JP/Start-Collecting-Daemons-of-Slaanesh) (with some daemonettes).

Thus, I was wondering: would it be possible for me, if I want to use Slaves to darkness as main army, to use the daemonettes of Slaanesh in a game (with official rules)?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Each faction lists which other factions can be taken as allies. For the Slaves to Darkness, that includes Hedonites of Slaanesh.

> 25.8 ALLIES
>
> Below a faction’s Pitched Battle profiles table, you will find a list
> of allies that can be taken in an army from that faction (see 27.1).
> The allies list will detail which factions you can take allied units
> from and any restrictions that apply to their use. Allied units cannot
> be generals.

> 27.1 ALLIED UNITS
>
> 1 in 4 units in your army can be allies (see 25.8). Allied units are ignored when determining if the units in the army are from a single faction.

| FACTION | ALLIES |
| --- | --- |
| Slaves to Darkness | Beasts of Chaos, Blades of Khorne, Disciples of Tzeentch, Maggotkin of Nurgle, Hedonites of Slaanesh |

Comment: Awesome, the answer is very clear. Can I ask you where you get the citation from? And also, I have been told that in order to make an alliance between them, I should use the mark of Slaanesh on my Slaves to Darkness army: is this true?

Comment: @FrsLry I don't see anything *requiring* you to take Mark of Slaanesh on your StD units, but it is thematic

Comment: Ok, perfect, awesome then!